# Fragment Transaction is added to backstack even if disallowAddToBackStack is called

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

Here is a sample code to repo this bug:

If I replace 3 fragments in a row, and disable the second one to be added into the backstack.

```
        fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fargmentA = FragmentA()
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fargmentA).addToBackStack("a").commitAllowingStateLoss();

        val fargmentB = FragmentB()
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fargmentB).disallowAddToBackStack().commitAllowingStateLoss();
        
        val fargmentC = FargmentC()
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fargmentC).addToBackStack("c").commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

After the above transaction, I called popBackStack():

```
  val count = fragmentManager.backStackEntryCount;
        for(i in 0 until count ){
            fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
        }
```

I can still see the onCreateView() method is called from FragmentB which I disallow add to backstack.

Is this a known bug or just how fragment manager behaves?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think `disallowAddToBackStack()` is doing? All it does is make it so that you can't call `addToBackStack` on that individual `FragmentTransaction`, as per [its documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#disallowAddToBackStack()).

Comment: @ianhanniballake right, so it means that i didnt add the fragment b transaction into backstack right? why does popBackStack() resume the fragmentB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two main things to keep in mind:

1. `replace()` is the equivalent to calling `remove()` on every fragment currently added to that container, then calling `add()` with your new fragment, so that transaction with `fragmentC` is going to remove `fragmentB` as part of its operation
2. `popBackStack()` puts you exactly in the state you were in before the transaction. This means that `fragmentC` gets removed (the opposite of `add()`) and fragmentB gets added (the opposite of `remove()`)

This means that it is expected that popping your `fragmentC` transaction will bring `fragmentB` back - your `disallowAddToBackStack()` just means that your `fragmentB` transaction can **never** be reversed.

This actually has some serious implications when it comes to mixing `addToBackStack()` and non-`addToBackStack()` fragment transactions on the same container: after you do your `fragmentB` transaction, **there's no way to get back to `fragmentA`**.

Generally, this means that if that was actually want you wanted, you replace your non-back stack `fragmentB` transaction with

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack()
val fargmentB = FragmentB()
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fargmentB).addToBackStack("b").commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

This would ensure that all transactions use `addToBackStack()` and the reversal works as expected at each step.

Note that every one of your transactions should use `setReorderingAllowed(true)` as per the [Fragment transaction guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#reordering). This will prevent cases where fragments are moved up to higher lifecycle levels then moved immediately back down and ensures that combined operations like a `popBackStack()` and `commit()` together run as a single atomic transition.